# Under what conditions does $X^TX = A^TA$ imply $X = A$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's say we have access to a matrix $C_{D \times D}$ which equals $X^TX$ for some matrix $X_{k \times D}$, but we don't know what $X$ is. If we decompose $C$ as $A^TA$, can we always say that $A$ would be exactly equal to $X$. If not, when can we say this?

In another scenario, we have a matrix $S_{k \times k}$ which equals $XX^T$ for the same $k \times D$ matrix $X$. If we decompose $S$ as $BB^T$, can we say that $X = B$? If not, when can we say this?

Comment: When you say $C_{D \times D}$, you mean a matrix $D \times D$ (columns and rows) I assume. If you are, its common to use capitals for matrices and not capitals for numbers. Trying being consistent because its annoying and can be confusing (or define your notation).

Comment: Also, how is this related to machine learning? I am curious.

Comment: @Pinocchio $X_{k \times D}$, the way I have stated it, is a mean-centered data matrix with $k$ points in $\mathbb{R}^D$. $C_{D \times D}$ is the covariance matrix. $S_{k \times k}$ is the matrix of pair-wise inner products. The question I have asked is related to dimensionality reduction. [PCA](http://goo.gl/OjUmWU) works with $C$ and [MDS](http://goo.gl/EvcKhT) works with $S$. I am sorry about the confusion in the notation; but it is not uncommon in the ML literature to refer to the dimension of the original data as $D$ and the dimension of the reduced data as $d$. I just adopted that.

Comment: I've removed the tags anyway, since the actual question is not about statistics or machine learning.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Sure, no problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that $Q$ is orthogonal matrix, i.e. $Q^t=Q^{-1}$. Then $A^tA=A^tQ^TQA=(QA)^t(QA)$.

Comment: Thanks, that answers the question.